# Sending webhook request to firebase https onRequest cloud function got 403 response

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I registered one of my firebase cloud function as webhook URL in ABC. ABC will send webhook request to my function URL if there is any event. But webhook request always got 403 response, and my cloud function never got triggered.

So my question is will firebase block any IP from sending request to cloud functions server? Or is there any possible reason the external request got 403 error?

Thanks!

Comment: What you have right now lacks details.  If you're not willing to share enough details for anyone to reproduce the issue, you should contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: It looks like I have to give ```allUsers``` permission to be cloud functions invoker in GCP console.

Answer (score 2):

I got answers from [this post](http://%20%20%20%20%20Go%20to%20the%20cloud%20function%20tab%20%20%20%20%20Select%20your%20cloud%20function%20(check%20box)%20%20%20%20%20Click%20%22Add%20members%22%20under%20Permissions%20tab%20in%20the%20right%20side%20%20%20%20%20Enter%20%22allUsers%22%20under%20%22New%20memebers%22%20%20%20%20%20Select%20Role%20as%20%22Cloud%20Functions%20-%3E%20Cloud%20Functions%20Invoker%22%20%20%20%20%20Save%20%20%20%20%20Test%20your%20cloud%20function%20by%20just%20pasting%20it%20in%20the%20browser)

```
1. Go to the cloud function tab
2. Select your cloud function (check box)
3. Click "Add members" under Permissions tab in the right side
4. Enter "allUsers" under "New memebers"
5. Select Role as "Cloud Functions -> Cloud Functions Invoker"
6. Save
7. Test your cloud function by just pasting it in the browser
```

Comment: Functions deployed with the Firebase CLI should not require these steps.  The CLI automatically adds allUsers permissions on the first deployment.  If you observe something different, you should send your reproductions steps to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Sure. But the thing is above steps really solve the problem. I will reach out to firebase support team

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation

It appears that Google now requires these functions to be explicitly whitelisted to the `allUsers` user...